# Canon printer with scanner mg3640 deriver

Tags: printing, scanner

How to install Canon printer with scanner mg3640 deriver.

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting

Comment: To add to @brian_p's link, the driver they offer on Cannon's site is from 2015 and builds to an 'rpm' - for distros like Fedora or RHEL. Now, in theory you could compile it and get the RPM (going from the readme file included) and then use alien to convert it to .deb, but those hoops and the age of the driver make me think that'd be a futile effort.